# How to run Jest tests with Yarn without any prompts?

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, teamcity, jestjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to run my Jest unit tests in Team City but I always end up getting the prompt as shown below.

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

I tried running `yarn test a` to run all the tests. But once the tests have completed execution, I'm still getting the same prompt. I tried `yarn test a q` but that doesn't work. I also tried `yarn test a --forceExit` and `yarn test a --bail` but nothing happens, I still get the prompt. How can I run all my Jest tests without getting this prompt as there will be no interaction when running through Team City? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try to pass `--ci`  option?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor I tried "yarn test --ci" and "yarn test a --ci". But neither of them work :(

Comment: oh. yarn... try ` --silent`

Comment: Still no luck, getting the same prompt. Guess I'll have to add the ci true thing to my package json. Because that works.

Comment: oh. glad to help you.  as I said changing package.json is alternative solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TeamCity, edit the setting for your configuration, then select `Parameters` on the side.

Click `Add a new Parameter`, and in the dialog popup that appears, under `Kind:` select `Environment variable (env.)`.

Set the name to `env.CI` and set the value to `true`. Click `Save`.

Next time you run your build, your build should auto-run the tests and move on.

For bonus points (and if you are the administrator) go to `Administration` then under `Projects` edit the <Root project>. Click `Parameters` on the side and set the `env.CI` parameter to `true` so you don't have to set this for future projects.

Answer (score 12):

```
--ci
```

When this option is provided, Jest will assume it is running in a CI environment. This changes the behavior when a new snapshot is encountered. Instead of the regular behavior of storing a new snapshot automatically, it will fail the test and require Jest to be run with --updateSnapshot.  [link](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#ci)

Also, you can change `package.json` to:

```
"test": "CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
```

which works great.

Your other option is to set `CI` in the command like any variable:

```
CI=true yarn test
```

Comment: I tried "yarn test --ci" and "yarn test a --ci". But I'm still getting the same prompt. Is there another way that'd work without making any changes to the package json?

Answer (score 2):

```
yarn test --coverage
```

Will run only once (with coverage) and returns 0 on success and 1 on failure.

Comment: This will still cause the command to hang if no files have been changed since the last commit. The difference is that it will create a `coverage` folder under the project,  and print some more information.

Comment: this does not work for me!

Answer (score 2):

The following command worked for me.

- `CI=true yarn test`

Comment: Please provide an explanation. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).